# CakePHP - Saving an hasMany through association

Tags: cakephp

I'm currently trying to figure out how to save a hasMany through relationship.

My tables are:

cards:
`id,
name`

colors:
`id,
name,
color`

card_colors (associated with the model CardColor):
`id,
card_id,
color_id,
cost`

hasMany through Association:

```
Card hasMany CardColor
Color hasMany CardColor
CardColor belongsTo Card
CardColor belongsTo Color
```

In `Card::beforeSave()`, I'm going to reconstruct my `$data` variable so that it has this structure:

```
array(
'Card' => array(
    'name' => 'theCard',
    'CardColor' => array(
        array(
            'card_id' => 4,
            'color_id' => 5,
            'cost' => 2
        ),
        array(
            'card_id' => 5,
            'color_id' => 2,
            'cost' => 3
        )
    )
)
)
```

However, I don't know how to get the card_id for the card that I am currently inserting. Is there a more Cake-y way of saving a hasMany through association (such as getting the card id automatically in some way while saving)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Use $this->Card-create() // or just $this->create() in the model
- In Card::beforeSave(), don't set the index CardColor[i][card_id]
- Do the save this way: $this->saveAssociated($data)

Comment: Thanks that worked except I used `array('deep' => true)` inside the saveAll() method instead of using `saveAssociated($data)`.